# Assembly Label: how is the actual label value calculated?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, label, segment, addressing

Background: I'm learning operating system and reading some linux source code, and I got a bit confused because the code is directly operating on the segment registers and label offsets. So I got the following question:

How is the actual label value calculated in assembly, for example, for the code below:

```
.text
  [Some code]
.data
  x: 64
```

is offset of x calculated by x - [.data] or x - [.text]?

I want to understand this because sometimes operating system code uses `seg cs` to directly set the segment value. In order to make sure the addressing is correct, I want to figure out how the label offset is calculated.

Comment: You did not show any use of that offset. In the typical case the offset is just a zero based virtual memory address because linux that you mentioned uses flat memory space. The only place you should see stuff like `segcs` is in 16 bit real mode startup code and that assumes you have loaded the segment register with the appropriate base address used by your build process.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! So one use of the offset is in bootsect.s:
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/nico/archive/+/v0.99-pl8/boot/bootsect.S#236
I know that we don't need to worry about if the offset is calculated by x - [.data] or x - [.text] because there is only .text in bootsect.s. But I'm wondering if the data root_dev is defined under a .data section, should we set cs to [.text] or [.data], in order to correctly refer to root_dev?

Comment: That is very special code, because it relocates itself and it's real mode code. The `cs` for the copy is set to `INITSEG` on line 68. Memory references from that point on will use the new location.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I think I know how this specific piece of code is working. But I'm wondering how the label offset is calculated? Like in the example above, is it calculated based on .text or .data? i.e. does .data start a new segment?

Comment: In typical context those are sections not segments and the toolchain deals with zero based virtual addresses. In this bootsector `.text` is presumably linked to zero address too. `.data` might not even be allowed.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks!

Comment: where .text and .data are has to do with how they are linked.  x will be relative to .data naturally.  but once/while linking the distance from the start of .text will also be known to the linker so that it can patch up what is needed.  What happened when you tried this with another line of two of code and linker settings that varied the address for the start of .text and .data?

Comment: I didn't try this code, I was just thinking that for the bootsect.s code,
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/nico/archive/+/v0.99-pl8/boot/bootsect.S#236
If root_dev is defined in a separate .data section, how should the segment register be set in order to correctly refer to the address of root_dev?